# Issue with some code

Tags: android, textview, runtime-error

I'm having a bug with this code because the app allways crash when I click on the TextView

This is the XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="dfx.com.asistentepredicaciondfx.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/textView2"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Dia"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="66dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Horas"
        android:layout_marginStart="158dp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView4"
        tools:layout_constraintBaseline_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView3" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the Java code

```
   package dfx.com.asistentepredicaciondfx;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * Created by Diego Utreras on 2/3/2018.
 */

public class ContentMain extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView dia;
    int anio;
    int mes;
    int diaM;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

        dia = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        dia.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
       final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        anio = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mes =  c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        diaM = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

        final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault());

        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                dia.setText(dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
            }
        }
                ,anio,mes,diaM);
        datePickerDialog.show();

        }
}
```

In android studio it doesn´t show me any errors buy when I run it in the emulator and click in the TextView2 for it to show the DatePicker the app crashes and close. Can someone tell me please what I need to change or what i need to put for the App stop crashing.

Comment: post the log errors

Comment: the error is in run time,. Not compiling

Comment: i suggest to set onclick insdie oncreate remove it from view and try

Comment: I'll try but the thing is I want that when touched the textview a DatePicker displays on the screen, not automatically

Comment: Hi Diego - could you please edit your post to include the errors that you see at runtime? Thanks!

Comment: The error in runtime is that the App crashes. When I touch the TextView it closes inmediatly

Answer (score 0):

This is the default constructor for `DatePickerDialog`

```
DatePickerDialog (Context context, 
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener, 
            int year, 
            int month, 
            int dayOfMonth)
```

I see two problems with your code.

1) First parameter is `year` (`anio`) and you are setting the value of DAY_OF_WEEK (`diaM`).
2) `diaM` - value is being set for `DAY_OF_WEEK` but it should be `DAY_OF_MONTH`

So try this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    anio = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mes =  c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    diaM = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault());

    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

            dia.setText(dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
        }
    }, anio, mes, diaM);

    datePickerDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to see if that fixes the bug. Also I'm new developing in Android so I'm not related with all the stuff on Android, thats why I make mistakes like this one. I only now Java a bit

Comment: The problem persists. It keeps closing when I click the Textview. Is there something else than can be wrong? Like another class perhaps. If it can be in another place I can upload that code also.

Comment: Do you have any other code on `onCreate()`? Or click listeners on any another `TextViews`? Show other code on in this `Activitiy`

Comment: All the code of the XML and the Java class is above where I make the question updated. Dont now if this is relevant but I made the proyect a NavigationDrawer one. Thats why the XML and the Java classes are ContentMain and doesn't ActivityMain. The code above is everything I have in the ContentMain XML and Java